# Poetry fail to install in github actions using deploy key

Tags: github-actions, ssh-keys, python-poetry

I have a Python project using Poetry, and I need to access another private repo called `another_pgk` on Github when running the Github Actions. So I use https://github.com/webfactory/ssh-agent to setup my ssh key, this key is a deploy key for `another_pgk` that enables me to only have read access to this `another_pgk` repo. In my `pyproject.toml`, I have the private repo added as:

```
another_pgk= {git = "git@github.com:username/another_pgk.git", branch = "main"}
```

It seems that the ssh key is added successfully because after the step of setting up the ssh key, the action script is able to clone the code by `git clone git@github.com:username/another_pgk.git`. But if I run `Poetry install`, it fails, with the following message:

```
HangupException

  The remote server unexpectedly closed the connection.

  at C:\Program Files (x86)\pipx\venvs\poetry\lib\site-packages\dulwich\protocol.py:220 in read_pkt_line
      216| 
      217|         try:
      218|             sizestr = read(4)
      219|             if not sizestr:
    > 220|                 raise HangupException()
      221|             size = int(sizestr, 16)
      222|             if size == 0:
      223|                 if self.report_activity:
      224|                     self.report_activity(4, "read")

The following error occurred when trying to handle this error:


  HangupException

  Warning: Permanently added the ECDSA host key for IP address '192.30.255.112' to the list of known hosts.

  Load key "C:\\Users\\runneradmin/.ssh/key-52016bfd3f72432689e062517edb001705ef0a8d1af12eb63b188417c75ca43e": invalid format

  git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).


  at C:\Program Files (x86)\pipx\venvs\poetry\lib\site-packages\dulwich\client.py:1151 in fetch_pack
      1147|         with proto:
      1148|             try:
      1149|                 refs, server_capabilities = read_pkt_refs(proto.read_pkt_seq())
      1150|             except HangupException as exc:
    > 1151|                 raise _remote_error_from_stderr(stderr) from exc
      1152|             (
      1153|                 negotiated_capabilities,
      1154|                 symrefs,
      1155|                 agent,
```

so, why is that, and how do I fix it? or does poetry supports deploy key or not?

Answer (score 0):

okay, i think the root cause is the path cannot take "/" as path seperator for windows for ssh-agent, reported at https://github.com/webfactory/ssh-agent/issues/162